# SQL Datetime: add time on Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Having database servers on both SQL Server and Oracle Server,

I couldn't find any homogeneous answer for adding time to a date.

What I would do on **SQL Server**:

```
select dateadd(minute, 1, CreationDate) from comments
```

and on **Oracle Server** (even though this isn't a pretty solution):

```
select CreationDate + (1/1440) from comments
```

1440 being the minutes in a day.

Is there any solution that would work on both servers?

Comment: Does SQL Server support ANSI SQL? `creationdate + interval '1' minute` (which works in Oracle)

Comment: Unfortunately, date/time handling is one area where SQL Server is still vastly different from the standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that doesn't seem to work under SQL Server.

Comment: Why is it important to find a solution that works on both servers?   Maybe there is another solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: There could be. I needed a solution that works on both servers, so I can (when setting the queries in my code) make abstraction of the SQL engine and not worry if it would work on one or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this works on Oracle but this works on SQL Server (Tested on 2014 Ex. Edition):

`select CreationDate + (1./1440) from comments`

The only thing that's different to your oracle solution is the dot behind 1  - just to tell sql server that this is not an integer column but a float.