# How to combine database types into a single query?

Tags: sql, types, casting

I have a database with the following columns:

**LOCAL_DEPART** [*Timestamp*]

**DEPART_DIFF** [*Integer*]

**LOCAL_ARRIVE** [*Timestamp*]

**ARRIVE_DIFF** [*Integer*]

I'm trying to write a query that will take the `local_depart` and add the `depart_diff` to it (which is an integer representing minutes), and getting a result back.

for example: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (local_depart + depart_diff < 4:00 pm)`

The portion in the parenthesis obviously needs to change, but that's the type of query I'm looking for. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Datetime: add time on Oracle and SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433408/sql-datetime-add-time-on-oracle-and-sql-server)